# What is the point and how to organize 15 minutes research presentation for job interview?

Tags: job-search, job

How to be technically specific enough, and to present research history and future plans in 15 minutes? Should I  plan as a presentation for a conference or should I follow strict rules for a job interview? How to avoid irking with oversimplification. Because a lot of methods I use are really complex.

Job is at a highly research-intensive university for TT position.

Comment: Surely how well you manage the questions you ask are precisely the skills the prospective employers wish to evaluate.

Comment: The "how to" question seems hard to answer without specific knowledge about your work. Of course, you need to leave out some details, and it's up to your judgement where to draw the line.

Comment: @lighthouse keeper ES and technology. How much of specific knowledge should I include?

Comment: Some. The majority of the talk should be motivation and big-picture level presentation. Maybe select one portion of your work (the one you're most proud of) to show off technical details.

Comment: What is "keeper ES and technology"?!

Comment: I've always thought these were pretty silly exercises; seems reasonable (or even good) to question the practice.

Answer (score 4):

> How to be technically specific enough, and to present research history and future plans in 15 minutes? Should I plan as a presentation for a conference or should I follow strict rules for a job interview? How to avoid irking with oversimplification. Because a lot of methods I use are really complex.

Some standard but important tips:

**1. Identify your audience.** Are the people who will be at the interview presentation in your specific sub-area? In your field but not your subfield? In a totally different field? The talk you should give should be completely different depending on the audience. In general, you want to err on the side of being for a really general audience.

**2. Practice, practice, practice.** You need to give your talk to a similar audience 2 or 3 times. Get feedback; make sure people tell you if they were lost or didn't understand.

**3. Focus on high-level points: more about problems and research goals, less about the solution.** This is 15 minutes; you're not going to be able to go into any details. Just say the most important implications: our research resulted in an X% improvement in Y for Z. Or, my research goal is to transform X by bringing ideas from Y and applying Z. Don't get into any technical jargon, definitely don't get into any notation or symbols, unless you are very very sure your audience will understand it.

**4. Use as many examples as possible.** Examples are the best way to get your audience to understand what you are doing, without being dishonest, but also without being too complex. You can say that your research is much more general after the examples, but start with a simple motivating example that explains what your research is about.

Comment: +1 Because your answer is structured so that your answer itself provides an example of what you advise doing. *(Revision of a comment I made 40 minutes ago, in which I inadvertently used the word "example" for what is now the second appearance of the word "answer".)*